# I can't compile opencv samples with VS2010 on vista

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, windows-vista

I am using visual studio 2010 on windows vista. I want to compile a sample file of OPENCV named "find_obj.cpp" created by liuliu.

Here is the address of source code.

https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/c/find_obj.cpp

Other opencv codes works well but I couldn't compile this. please help

I've installed all of the libraries needed and opencv. Other opencv projects of mine are working fine.

My error is "unresolved externals"
here it is,

> Error  14  error LNK1120: 11 unresolved externals
>   Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol `"class cvflann::Logger & __cdecl cvflann::logger(void)"` `(?logger@cvflann@@YAAAVLogger@1@XZ)` referenced in function `"public: virtual void __thiscall cvflann::KDTreeIndexParams::print(void)const "` `(?print@KDTreeIndexParams@cvflann@@UBEXXZ`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem. In this sample it uses flann functions and I added the opencv_flann220d.lib to libraries section in visual studio. Now, program compiles with no error.

And I learned that if you're getting "unresolved externals" error it is mostly because of missing of include directories or libraries.

greetings

Answer (score 1):

I'm running MS Visual Studio 2010 and OpenCV on Vista too.

From my own experience: with this combination of operating system and Visual Studio you can use more modern versions of OpenCV. OpenCV 3.4.0 will be 100% working on your PC.

Comment: Could you be more detail?

Comment: I downloaded source files of OpenCV 3.4.0. I also downloaded the latest version of CMake and installed it. I generated OpenCV source for MS Visual Studio 2010 via CMake. So I built OpenCV binaries on my own PC. Later I copied these binaries and OpenCV headers to my second PC that works under Vista. I copied there some test project, that uses OpenCV 3.4.0 and this project have been built perfectly  and it works absolutely correctly

Answer (score 0):

What compiler errors do you get? Have you installed OpenCV and linked the appropriate libraries?

Comment: I've installed all of the libraries needed and opencv. Other opencv projects of mine are working fine.

My error is "unresolved externals"